# Using Javascript to change an Image src

Tags: javascript

I have a really simple piece of code that is supposed to change the img src of my img called innings. It's pretty straightforward, that onclick I call the function `changeImage`, and depending on the current `src` of the image, I change it to the next iteration of images. The code looks like:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        function changeImage() {
            var mySrc = document.getElementById('inning');
            alert(mySrc.src);
            if (mySrc.src = "1st.png") {
                alert('im in here');
                mySrc.src = "2nd.png";
            }
            else if (mysrc.src = "2nd.png")
                mysrc.src = "3rd.png";
            else if (mysrc.src = "3rd.png")
                mysrc.src = "4th.png";
            else if (mysrc.src = "4th.png")
                mysrc.src = "5th.png";
            else if (mysrc.src = "5th.png")
                mysrc.src = "6th.png";
            else if (mysrc.src = "6th.png")
                mysrc.src = "7th.png";
            else if (mysrc.src = "7th.png")
                mysrc.src = "8th.png";
            else if (mysrc.src = "8th.png")
                mysrc.src = "9th.png";
            else if (mysrc.src = "9th.png")
                mysrc.src = "10th.png";
            else if (mysrc.src = "10th.png")
                mysrc.src = "1st.png";

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>      <label>SlowPitch Player Rotation</label></center>
    <br /><br />

    <Center>
        <img id="inning" src="1st.png" 
                onclick='changeImage()' />
    </Center>
```

Now the problem I'm having is that every time I hit the image, the `changeImage()` function hits the alert, letting me know the `src` is still `1st.png`; meanwhile my first alert tells me that I have `2nd.png` as my `src`.

Comment: It's `if (mySrc.src == "1st.png") {`

Comment: I'd suggest `mysrc.getAttribute('src')`, since the `mysrc.src` property (usually) returns an absolute path, even if the path in the attribute is relative. Also [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FElement%2Flabel) is used to associate a form-element (`input`, `select` or `textarea`) with a text-caption; and [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FElement%2Fcenter) is deprecated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `=` which is assignment. The value is getting assigned to the variable; you want to check for equality in your if statements. Use either `==` (are they equal?) or `===` (are they equal AND same type?).

Answer (score 4):

All the `if (mySrc.src = "image_name") {` should be

```
if (mySrc.src == "1st.png") {
```

Two == means equal to

One = means set value to

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, your main problem was not using the right `===` or `==` for comparison and referencing the `.src` propery will return an absolute path so your comparisons probably wouldn't have worked for that reason either.

Anyway, I would suggest a new and more compact code design where you [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) up your code (remove redundancy) like this.

This parses the number out of the string rather than checking for an exact match which saves all the `if/else` comparisons and once you have the number, you can get the next name by indexing directly into an array of names.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function changeImage() {
        var names = ["1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7th", "8th", "9th", "10th"];
        var mySrc = document.getElementById('inning');
        // parse the number out of the existing .src string
        var matches = mySrc.src.match(/(\d+).*?\.png$/);
        if (matches) {
            // since array is 0 indexed and names are 1 indexed, we don't need to add one
            // as it is already one more than it was
            var num = parseInt(matches[1], 10);
            if (num >= names.length) {
                num = 0;
            }
            mySrc.src = names[num] + ".png";
        }
    }
</script>
```

FYI, if your filenames only had the number in them (like `img1.png`) without the suffixes on them, then the code could be even simpler as you wouldn't even need the array of name because you could just manufacture the new name from the previous number.

Comment: Thank you; I was a couple of minutes away from doing much the same (though I was planning to go through various iterations of improvements to explain them incrementally). You've just saved quite a bit of time, so +1 and thank you! =D

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is, that you do not compare two values in your if statement but instead assign a value:

```
if (mySrc.src = "1st.png")
```

should read

```
if (mySrc.src === "1st.png")
```

Else you assign "1st.png" to mySrc.src over and over again.